# How to turn pandas data frame w/ row per unique term & date into df which contains 1 row per date, w/ unique terms + their values as columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv, or data frame, that looks something along the lines of this, but includes several hundred thousand rows:

```
df = {'Date': {0: '2014-01-01,
  1: '2014-01-01',
  2: '2014-01-01',
  3: '2014-01-02',
  4: '2014-01-02'},
 'Name': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'Rob',
  3: 'Mel',
  4: 'Rob'},
 'Rank': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 6},
 'Count': {0: 10, 1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 11, 4: 4}}
```

The names recur for each of the dates, but change in count and ranking. Instead of having one row per date for every single one of these names, as I do now, I'd like to arrange my data frame so that there is a value for every date. That is to say, I'd like my table to look like this:

```
Date        John_Rank   Rob_Rank    Mel_rank  John_count   Mel_count   Rob_count  
2014-01-01    ...         ...          ...        ...         ...
2014-01-02    ...         ...          ...        ...         ...
```

I'd like to use this format to calculate the differences in ranks. I've come up against this several times before, but haven't had this many rows to deal with for a long stretch of dates — I've only done this manually up until now. Any advice would be very much appreciated!!

Comment: Please clarify what you want to be *in* those columns.  Your sample data contains two "John" values for the same date.  What do you intend to have in the John_Rank column for that date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with default `aggfunc='mean'`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Date': {0: '2014-01-01',
  1: '2014-01-01',
  2: '2014-01-01',
  3: '2014-01-02',
  4: '2014-01-02'},
 'Name': {0: 'John',
  1: 'John',
  2: 'Rob',
  3: 'Mel',
  4: 'Rob'},
 'Rank': {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 5, 4: 6},
 'Count': {0: 10, 1: 3, 2: 9, 3: 11, 4: 4}}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df
   Count        Date  Name  Rank
0     10  2014-01-01  John     1
1      3  2014-01-01  John     3
2      9  2014-01-01   Rob     2
3     11  2014-01-02   Mel     5
4      4  2014-01-02   Rob     6

df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date', columns='Name')
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
print df
            Count_John  Count_Mel  Count_Rob  Rank_John  Rank_Mel  Rank_Rob
Date                                                                       
2014-01-01         6.5        NaN          9          2       NaN         2
2014-01-02         NaN         11          4        NaN         5         6
```

Or if you want [`swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.swaplevel.html) `multiindex` in columns:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Date', columns='Name')
df.columns  =  df.columns.swaplevel(0,1)
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]
print df
            John_Count  Mel_Count  Rob_Count  John_Rank  Mel_Rank  Rob_Rank
Date                                                                       
2014-01-01         6.5        NaN          9          2       NaN         2
2014-01-02         NaN         11          4        NaN         5         6
```